# default scrapbook saved location in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I saved a website using **scrapbook** addon in firefox.I  can able to open from scrap book 
   options .

But i am unable to find the location  where it is saved.Please help me.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: A link to the actual plug-in would help tremendously.

Comment: The answer was useful so i'm not voting down, but this is not suitable for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

One way to find out where the app is currently saving:

- save a page with the Scrapbook app (right click -> save page -> root folder)
- then click the link for that page when the Scrapbook app popup appears notifying you that the save is complete
- look in the URL bar, and after the "file:///", the path on your computer to the saved page is shown

For Windows 7, the default location for me was:

```
C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/{random string}.default/ScrapBook/data
```

Where the brackets represent text that will be different on different computers.

This answer is written for the Scrapbook app installed in Firefox.  Specifically:

Firefox page: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/scrapbook/

page for the app itself: http://amb.vis.ne.jp/mozilla/scrapbook/

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who needs a solution to this. Another way to do it is to open Mozilla, go to the scrapbook tab and click on "Show in sidebar" (that will make all of your links available for viewing and selecting on the side of the browser) From there you will see (under the sidebar searchbar/tool) a dropdown menu for "Tools" . Once you click on tools, it gives you multiple options including "Open Data Folder"